# envsubst not working as expected in a bash for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use bash's `envsubst` to substitute an environment variable into a file. Here's a simple example that fails to work as expected:

Create a file with a variable substitution in it:

```
echo 'Filename: ${FILE}' > test.txt
```

Now try to use envsubst in a for loop:

```
for FILE in `ls`; do envsubst < test.txt; done

Filename:
```

The result is just `Filename:` the substitution fails.

Echo works as expected in this context:

```
for FILE in `ls`; do echo Filename: ${FILE}; done

Filename: test.txt
```

I don't understand why echo would work and envsubst would fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because in the for loop `FILE` is a shell variable and it is not actually part of the environment, so it is not passed to envsubst's environment.

Try this

```
for FILE in `ls`; do
    env | grep FILE;
done
```

and compare it to this

```
for FILE in `ls`; do
    export FILE;
    env | grep FILE;
done
```

So if you want to make `FILE` an environment variable you need to use `export` builtin before.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to export the variable and, optionally if you are paranoid/security-minded, name it on the command line:

```
export FILE
envsubst < template #all exported environment avail in template
envsubst '${FILE}' < template #only FILE available
```